# Replace first nth occurences of string1 by string2 after string3, within a file (i.e multiline pattern)

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I'm using sed trying to replace after a multiline pattern trying all sort of things like

```
sed -i 'N;{string3} s/string1/string2/g;n'
```

but I don't even know if it is possible. Could somebody provide me some help?

Thanks!

Comment: a sample of source and result could be a bit better for understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but perhaps this is what you want (in awk):

```
awk 'x { gsub(/string1/,"string2") ; x=0 } /string3/ { x=1 } 1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `awk`,

```
awk '/string3/{n=1;c=1} n && /string1/ && c++ <= 5{ gsub(/string1/,"string2",$0)}1' yourfile
```

If this is not what you want, Please edit your question with sample file and expected output.